# How to calculate expected payoff and optimal bid in this auction?

Tags: game-theory, auction-theory

> There is a seller $S$ with an object with quality $x$. The seller knows this quality; the buyer $B$ does not but beliefs that $x$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,M]$ with $0<M\leq2$.
>
> With true quality $x$, the seller values the object with $x$ and the buyer with $x^2$.
>
> The game is:
>
> 1. the seller learns $x$,
> 2. the buyer makes a bid $b$,
> 3. the seller accepts or rejects,
> 4. the payoff to the seller is $b-x$ and the payoff to the buyer is $x^2-b$. If the bid is rejected both get $0$. For each value of $M$, find *a* PBE of this game.

What I have done so far:

Note that for uniform distribution on $[0,M]$ the pdf is $f(x) = \frac{1}{M}$ and the cdf is $F(x) = \frac{x}{M}$ for $x \in [0,M]$.

Clearly, for the seller the optimal strategy is to accept bids when $b>x$ and reject bids $b<x$. The expected payoff of the buyer is then:
$$Eu_B = \int_0^b x^2 - b\ \textrm{d}F(x)$$
Where $F(x)$ is cdf of the uniform distribution. Correct?

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/380856/684892) I understand that this is equivalent to:
$$Eu_B = \int_0^b (x^2 - b)f(x)\ \textrm{d}x$$

Substituting the pdf the gives:
$$Eu_B = \int_0^b \frac{(x^2 - b)}{M}\ \textrm{d}x = \frac{\frac{1}{3} b^3 - b^2}{M}$$

Setting the derivative w.r.t. $b$ to zero:
$$\frac{\partial Eu_B}{\partial b} = \frac{b^2 - 2b}{M} = 0 \iff b = 2$$

But this doesn't make sense to me. Why would the buyer always bid 2, regardless of $M$? What am I missing here?

EDIT: I am not looking for a complete solution here, just some pointers in the right direction, or correction of any mistakes in my solution.

Comment: Just to say:  If $M≤1$ then the buyer should not bid at all (or bid a safe $0$) since either a bid would be declined or it would be accepted at a loss to the buyer.    That is to say, with $M≤1$ we have $b>x\implies b>x^2$.

Comment: In a similar vein, with $M=2$, if you actually bid $2$ your expectation is negative, so you can, again, improve your outcome by bidding $0$.  This, of course, is even more true if you foolishly  bid $2$ when $M<2$.