# Confusion over the density of sum of functions of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a real valued random variable with distribution $F$ and $V \sim$ $N(0,1)$ and $X,V$ are independent. For any map $f$ the density of $Y=f(X)+V$ is given by $p_Y(y)=\int\phi(y-f(x))dF(x)$ where $\phi(x)=(2\pi e^{x^2})^{-1/2}$.

I am not able to proceed further, what does it mean to integrate with respect to a distribution function. Any suggestions/hints would be helpful.

Comment: You cannot evaluate the integral without knowing what $F$ is.

Comment: Yes I agree. But why does $p_Y$ take this form?

Comment: If $X$ has a density $h$, you could replace $dF(X)$ by $h(x) dx$. (Not using $f$ for the density since you are already using $f$ for another meaning.) Otherwise, check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380785/what-does-it-mean-to-integrate-with-respect-to-the-distribution-function

Comment: The formual itself is wrong in general. Do you know that $X$ and$V$ are independent? If that is so then the result folows by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Pardon me. $X$ and $V$ are independent. No special assumption on $f$. They are any Borel maps.

Comment: What level of rigour do you require? I have an answer but it I need to swap a derivative and an integral. I expect this will be justified by DCT, but I don't have time right now to think about the details

Comment: Since the question is "what does it mean to integrate with respect to a distribution function", would not https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380785/what-does-it-mean-to-integrate-with-respect-to-the-distribution-function already answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F_Y(y) = \mathrm{Pr} (Y\leqslant y)$ then \begin{align*}
F_Y(y) &= \mathrm{Pr}(f(X)+V \leqslant y).
\end{align*} Since $X$ and $V$ are independent, $$\mathrm{Pr}(f(X)+V \leqslant y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{y-f(x)} \phi (v) \, dv\,dF(x). $$ Then* \begin{align*}
f_y(y) &= F_Y'(y) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi (y-f(x)) \, dF(x)
\end{align*} as required.

*In order to swap the integral and the derivative here I expect you will need to use dominated convergence. This might require some assumptions on $f$.

---

Edit: Let $$\psi(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y-f(x)} \phi (v) \, dv = \int_{-\infty}^{y} \phi (v-f(x)) \, dv $$ by a change of variables. Since $v \mapsto \phi (v-f(x))$ is continuous for each $x$, if the lower bound on the above integral was finite then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus would directly imply that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi (x,y)  =\phi(y-f(x)). \tag{$\ast$}$$ However, the lower bound is not finite, but $\phi$ decays rapidly so we might expect that $(\ast)$ is still true. Indeed, for $h>0$, \begin{align*}
\frac{\psi(x,y+h)-\psi(x,y)}{h} &= \frac1h \int_{y}^{y+h}\phi (v-f(x)) \, dv \\
&= \frac1h \int_0^{h}\phi (v+y-f(x)) \, dv.
\end{align*} Since $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous (its derivative is bounded) it follows that \begin{align*}
\bigg \vert \frac{\psi(x,y+h)-\psi(x,y)}{h} - \phi(y-f(x))\bigg \vert &\leqslant \frac1h  \int_0^{h} \big \vert \phi (v+y-f(x)) -\phi (y-f(x)) \big \vert \, dv \\
&\leqslant \frac{C}h\int_0^{h} \vert v \vert \, dv \\
&= Ch \to 0
\end{align*} as $h \to 0$. Hence, $(\ast)$ is true and this limit is uniform in $x$. Thus, \begin{align*}
F_Y'(y) &=\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1h \int_{y-f(x)}^{y+h-f(x)} \phi (v) \, dv\,dF(x)\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{h\to0}\frac1h \int_{y-f(x)}^{y+h-f(x)} \phi (v) \, dv\,dF(x) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi_y(x,y) \,dF(x) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi (y-f(x)) \, dF(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: If you need more of an explanation let me know and I'll add more detail.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say as how you computed the derivative of the integral in the last step.